# Are UI element ID's in a fragment automatically able to be accessed by the parent activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I can't seem to find any use cases of this, and Android Developers isnt being too clear about it.  I get that to access an activities UI elements from a Fragment I need to call getActivity.findViewById, and to access the fragments from an Activity its getFragment.findFragmentById.  But for the activity, can i just call findViewById if the Fragments is attached to the activity without calling anything else?  Essentially, does an Activity automatically know the view IDs of contained Fragments UI elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findViewById()` simply traverses the layout to find a view with that ID. When a `Fragment` is attached to an `Activity`, it is added to that `Activity`'s layout. So yes, you can access a `Fragment`'s views via their IDs from an `Activity`, but I would highly recommend against it. Add a public method on your `Fragment` that lets you make whatever change to those views that is desired, instead. This way you have the freedom to change your layout without worrying about breaking the host `Activity`.

Also, you don't need to use `getActivity().findViewById()` within a `Fragment` -- simply override `onViewCreated()`, and call `findViewById()` on the provided `view` instance. Or at any point in the lifecycle between `onCreateView()` and `onDestroyView()` you can use `getView().findViewById()`.

For example:

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    TextView fragmentTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_in_fragment);
}
```

Comment: Didn't even think of it like that, great advice thank you.  And I'll keep that in mind on the getActivity.findViewById() part, that should help going forward.